# Adding to coroutine context in expedia graphql-kotlin V4.x.x

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, graphql, kotlin-coroutines

I'm looking for a solution to update the coroutine context with my custom elements (e.g., MDCContext) in version 4.x.x of the Expedia GraphQL Kotlin library. I have tried implementing my own GraphQLRequestHandler and returning the result within a custom coroutine scope and context, but it hasn't been successful.

I noticed that in version 6.x.x of the library, there is documentation (https://opensource.expediagroup.com/graphql-kotlin/docs/server/graphql-context-factory) mentioning the ability to update the context (I tested it and it works), but I'm specifically interested in achieving this in version 4.x.x.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks :)